# How to do tcp load balancing in active/passive mode with more than 2 servers?

Tags: nginx, tcp, load-balancing

In my use case, I need to setup load balancer which can be nginx or something like that which supports TCP load balancing which will be connected to my backend service.

I want to do this in active/passive manner. I can have 5 load balancers instances on docker env and 5 backend service instances lets say NFS (maybe not on docker env).

Now I want my lb1 (load balancer 1) to route the request to nfs1 only unless it is down then route request to nfs2 or nfs3 so on.

```
lb1 ----- nfs1
lb2 ----- nfs2
:
:
lb5 ----- nfs5
```

I have tried it with nginx but it only supports 2 servers in active/passive mode with backup keyword.

```
    events {
    worker_connections  1024;
  }

   stream {
    upstream stream_backend {
        server 172.17.0.5:2049;
        server 172.17.0.7:2049 backup;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass stream_backend;
    }
}
```

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

By using Haproxy able to solve my issue.

```
defaults
    mode tcp

frontend haproxy
    bind *:80
    mode tcp
    timeout client  1s
    default_backend nfs


backend nfs
    mode tcp
    timeout connect 1s
    timeout server 1s
    server nfs1 172.17.0.7:2049 check
    server nfs2 172.17.0.5:2049 check backup
    server nfs3 172.17.0.8:2049 check backup
```

credits: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/failover-and-worst-case-management-with-haproxy/

Comment: are you able to perform nfs mounting with this?